# Changing HTTP response body

Tags: http, google-chrome-extension

How can I modify the HTTP response body of an iframe before it starts loading ?

I don't have access to the iframe content (because of same origin policy), but since I am doing a Chrome extension, I can use chrome.* APIs.

Comment: that would look like a man in the middle attack

Comment: I am developing a Chrome extension which let user navigate with a side panel. Using an iframe is easier than injecting the panel. However some websites forbid iframes, which is why I wanted to modify HTTP response body. But my intent is not to do anything unlawful.

Comment: i not saying you are. but basically you would be changing and reading the result of a request without the knowledge of the server nor of the client.

Comment: Ok so that explains why the Chrome APIs allow only to read the HTTP response it seems, but not to modify it.

Comment: It's not possible to modify the response body ([bug 104058](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058 "WebRequest API: allow extension to edit response body")). However, you can use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) with `"run_at": "document_start"` to run code before a document is rendered.

Comment: But content scripts can't access Javascript files (although they can access inline Javascript in <script> tags) of the page, I believe. I solved my problem by changing the whole design, and switching from using an iframe with a side panel, to create a new window with the panel. iframes are just too much trouble.